# Where does the output from the ssh ForceCommand script go?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I have a perl script that does a bunch of stuff like limit that commands that can be run through ssh (using SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND). The script works fine except for the fact that I am unable to see the output from the script (a bunch of things that I am printing) anywhere.

I have checked `/var/log/auth.log` but I don't see anything there.

Here is what the line in my `sshd_config` looks like:

`ForceCommand /some/path/my_script.pl`

I am running Ubuntu 12.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where does the output from the ssh ForceCommand script go?

The `ForceCommand` is the command that is run by the connecting user. Therefore if it produces some output, it goes to the user who is connecting.

Comment: What is the best way to pipe the output to a file where I can inspect it later. The reason is that I am connecting to SSH through another process (like NoMachine), so I can't really see what is being output

Comment: You (most probably) don't want to pipe all the output to some file, because you expect the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND will produce some output that will be send to the client. You should take care of logging itself in the perl script.